# Push msg.payload in nodered widget input

Tags: widget, node-red, amazon-kinesis, input-type-file

I'm using the AWS kinesis module in Node-red. There's a TypeInput input but it doesn't catch the payload that I generate from my linked node.

[image]

How can I assign this input aa a "dynamic variable" with the msg.payload value.

I tried {{payload}} but it just print the string itself: "{{payload}}". Is there any way I can pass a value (e.g. from a function) to a TypeInput to my widget?

P.S I'm using this module: https://github.com/Daniel-t/node-red-contrib-aws

Answer (score 0):

You can only use mustache `{{}}` syntax if the node explicitly supports it.

A quick look at the source code says this node does not support pulling in `msg` variables like that, in fact it doesn't look to support any dynamic settings of any fields.